# TortoiseHG and Google Code

Tags: mercurial, tortoisehg

I have been using TortoiseSVN for some time and I really like it. I was told TortoiseHg was worth checking out and "much better than SVN" so I am trying to get started with it.

I created a google code repository and I managed to upload one folder to it. However, when uploading another folder, I keep getting the error "abort: repository is unrelated"

Comment: I'd recommend reading on Mercurial (This is a fine tutorial http://hginit.com/) before trying to use TortoiseHg as if it were merely a better ToirtoiseSVN.

Comment: Ok I've read a bit. My conclusion is that the investment isn't worth the reward at this point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TortoiseHg and TortoiseSVN are not really comparable critters, as they are just GUI front-ends for two completely different version control systems. SVN is an older centralized stalwart, and Hg is a newer distributed system. Whether you should use SVN or Hg really depends on your use case, specifically:

- if your developers will ever be cut off from the central repository. Using Google Code would indicate 'no' since all developers need is a network connection, but off-network developers would still be a problem. Being a DVCS, Mercurial would allow off-network developers to work anywhere, only having to be on network to deal with server push/pull situations.
- if your developers care about file locking. SVN has built-in file locking and Mercurial does not.
- if your developers struggle with merging. Mercurial has [a more developed merge capability](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/a-tour-of-mercurial-merging-work.html) and handles conflicts more intelligently.

If you end up with three no's, then SVN may be the one for you.